# Attaching a debugger to a parcel built app

Tags: debugging, npm, webstorm, parceljs

I have my project setup as follows, within my package.json I have the follow:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dev": "parcel ./public/index.html --open",
  "build": "parcel build ./public/index.html NODE_ENV=production --no-source-maps --public-url ./public --out-dir ./dist",
  "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src --fix"
},
```

I can start my project by running: `npm run:dev` which starts as follows:

```
To debug the "dev" script, make sure the $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION string is specified as the first argument for the node command you'd like to debug.
For example:
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js"
  }

> impcentral@1.0.0 dev /Users/william/imp/src/impCentral
> parcel ./public/index.html --open

Server running at http://localhost:63188 - configured port 1234 could not be used.
```

As you can tell it does not stop at my break points within WebStorm. I've tried passing in the `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` within the package.json but to no avail.

Any ideas folks, open to trying this in Visual Studio Code too.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need running your NPM configuration in debugger unless you need debugging parcel itself. As your application, served by parcel, is run in browser, you have to use [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration to debug it.

- start your app by running `npm run dev` (either in WebStorm or in terminal)
- create a **JavaScript Debug** run configuration with your server URL (http://localhost:1234, or http://localhost:63188 in your case):

[image]

- select this configuration and press **Debug**

Comment: Is there no way to have VSCode launch Parcel besides manually launching it from a terminal window?

Comment: Is there a way to run the npm run dev command inside the configuration ? I tried but then it blocks the launch of the server.

Comment: No- a process added to *Before launch* has to return an exit code, the main process is waiting for its exit code to start and thus doesn't start until the first process terminates. But the `dev` script doesn't exit, it starts the server your application is hosted on, and it has to be running to make your application work. So you have to either start it separately or use the **Compound** run configuration to start both npm script and **Javascript Debug** run configuration concurrently